# How to convert a an int variable into string

Tags: python

*This question is on how to convert int to string.I am a novice in coding and I do not know how to convert an int value into a str value because , in python we cannot combine an int value along with a string value.So we have to convert the int value into string . Hope my question will help myself and future coders.*

```js
print("Type your age ")
    character_age = input()
    print("So your age is "+character_age)
    print("If your father is 20 years older what will be your fathers age ?")
    age_character = int(character_age)
    print("Father's age is " +age_character)
```

Comment: May i know what is the expected result? please added your input and output.. So i can help you :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I parse a string to a float or int in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379906/how-do-i-parse-a-string-to-a-float-or-int-in-python)

Comment: Try this : print("Father's age is \\(age_character)")

Answer (score 2):

**Input:**

```
print("Type your age ")
character_age = input()
print("So your age is "+character_age)
print("If your father is 20 years older what will be your fathers age ?")
age_character = int(character_age)+20 #add 20 with character age
print("Father's age is " + str (age_character )) # convert back into string for print
```

**Output:**

```
Type your age
5
So your age is 5
If your father is 20 years older what will be your fathers age ?
Father's age is 25
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `int()`:

```
x = '10'
int(x)
```

If you want to print an integer variable, you need to convert it back to a string using `str()`, as on your last line:

```
print("Father's age is " + str(age_character))
```

Answer (score 0):

`print()` is throwing TypeError. You cannot concatenate a `string` with an `int`. You would need to convert your `int` to a `string` using the `str` function

```
print("Type your age ")
character_age = input()
print("So your age is "+character_age)
print("If your father is 20 years older what will be your fathers age ?")
age_character = int(character_age)
print("Father's age is " +str(age_character))
```

Change `print("Father's age is " +age_character)` to:

```
print("Father's age is " +str(age_character))
```

or

```
print("Father's age is",age_character)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're already correctly converting the string `character_age` to an integer with the `int` constructor, although to be able to concatenate with another string you'll need to convert it back to a string, and since the printed message says the father's age should be 20 years older, you'll want to add 20 to it before converting to a string:

```
age_character = int(character_age) + 20
print("Father's age is " + str(age_character))
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean you are not getting the result you want ?

```
age_character = int(character_age)
```

The age_character variable already converted age into int. The only problem is you are trying to print a combination of string and int. You have convert it to string.

```
print(type(age_character))
print("Father's age is " + str(age_character) )
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot print a integer directly by using '+' operator as both datatypes are different. You need to convert that to a string.Try the below it will work.

```
print("Father's age is " + str(age_character))
```

The remaining code is correct

Answer (score 0):

You can do this like that(no need to convert into Strings):
make sure your (character_age must be an integer)

code:
{{ print "So your age is {character_age}".format(character_age=character_age) }}

{{ print "Father's age is {age_character}".format(age_character=age_character) }}

Answer (score 0):

Python's built in function `int()` can be used for this purpose.

```
>>> a = "10"
>>> int(a)
10
```

However, this works provided the string is convertible.

```
>>> a = "45.2"
>>> int(a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '45.2'
>>> b = "eleven"
>>> int(b)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'eleven'
```

[Link](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#int) to `int()` documentation.